# Get a list of all subdirectories in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying get an absolute path of all subfolders in `project_dirs`.

```
project_dirs='D:\MPhil\Model_Building\Models\TGFB\Vilar2006\SBML_sh_ver\vilar2006_SBSH_test7\Python_project3_IQM_project';
all_project_dirs=dir(project_dirs)
for i=all_project_dirs,
    full_dir=fullfile(project_dirs,i.name)
```

The above code gives a single string of all the subfolder directories concatenated together. How do I modify my code to get a cell array of these absolute paths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a function for that: `genpath()`. It will give you all directories recursively in a string, split by `:`. Use `strsplit()` to parse the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
all_project_dirs = {all_project_dirs([all_project_dirs.isdir]).name};
```

How it works:

1. This selects, among the elements of `all_project_dirs`, those that are directories;
2. From them it gets the `name` field;
3. The values of that field are contatenated into a cell array.

You may want to remove the first two directory names, which are always `'.'` and `'..'`:

```
all_project_dirs = all_project_dirs(3:end);
```

To obtain full paths, you can use [`strcat`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html):

```
all_project_dirs = strcat(project_dirs, filesep, all_project_dirs);
```

or, as suggested by Jørgen, use [`fullfile`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html):

```
all_project_dirs = fullfile(project_dirs, all_project_dirs);
```

Comment: Hi Luis, thanks for the response. This works great but would you happen to know how to get the absolute paths? When I try `strcat(all_project_dirs,i))` in a loop over `list_of_dirs` I still get a single string.

Comment: @user3059024 Sorry, I forgot that part. Edited

Comment: Another way, IMHO cleaner, is to use `fullfile`.  `all_project_dirs = fullfile(project_dirs, all_project_dirs);`